# at job facility for anacron?

Tags: cron, scheduled

Is there a tool for Ubuntu to schedule jobs similar to `at` but for `anacron` instead if plain `cron`? Eg.

```
echo "rm -Rf /tmp/workdata.$$.*" | at now + 99 minutes
```

It doesn't have to be via *anacron*, just whatever my scripts can rely on to run either at the scheduled time or when the server is back online.

If it's a scheduler only *root* can use I'll just wrap the calls with `sudo`

Answer (score 1):

Two game-changing things I've learned since then, that sort of resolve the matter:

- `at` daemon already runs jobs that fell behind schedule eg. due to server outage
- Using this property, `anacron` already sits on top of the `crontab` facility, and as bundled by default cannot schedule tasks at the hour/minute granularity, only month/day in its global config file in /etc (root owned).